# complex eigenvalues of matrix sum

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a set of (about 100) general real square matrices. Is it possible to determine whether none of their linear combinations has complex eigenvalues?

Comment: Nothing special about these "general real square matrices"?

Comment: perhaps, they have real eigenvalues

Comment: First of all, choose a basis of the space of linear combinations, so you'll have to work with fewer matrices.

Comment: Do the matrices have any other properties? they commute?

Comment: they are no other special properties, they do not commute, some of them are singular (1 or 2 eigenvalues are zero)